# handling windows paths in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a particular problem I'm facing with windows file paths in Jupyter notebook.

```
path = 'C:\apps\python'
print(path)
```

This gives `C:pps\python`

What I want to eventually do is to get a reference to the files in `path`

I was intending to do the following

```
files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
# do something with the list of files
```

However this throws up the error - `OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\x07pps\\python'`

Answer (score 2):

It's because `\a` is detected like a special character (like `\n` or `\t`).

The easiest way to fix your issue here is to use raw strings:

```
print(r'C:\apps\python')
```

Gives

```
C:\apps\python
```

You can parse a literal string to a raw string with:

```
path = r'{}'.format(path)
```

Comment: How do I create this string dynamically ? i'm passing the `path` variable that holds the string to other functions including `print`

Comment: Like any other strings, `volume = r'C:\app'; path = r'bin\python'; print(volume + path); print(os.path.join(volume, path))`, etc..

Comment: from the OP, `path = 'C:\apps\python'`. How can this be passed into `files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]` ? so that `listdir` and `join` considers have raw strings as arguments ?

Comment: I don't understand the issue here, `path = r'C:\apps\python'` and it's done

Comment: if I have a string variable `path = 'C:\apps\python'`, how do I generate the raw string of `path` ? is there a function I can apply on `path` to do that ? I do not want to type `r'C:\apps\python'` everywhere in my code.

Comment: to give some context - i have user input coming in from command line as `C:\apps\python`. I'm capturing this and want to use this in subsequent part of my code as in the original post.

Comment: this does not give the expected results. `
path = 'C:\apps\python'
print(path) #=> C:pps\python
path1 = r'{}'.format(path)
print(path1) #=> C:pps\python`